# Not perform action in menu items

Tags: android, menuitem

I have one action bar activity.when i am switching from one fragment to another fragment that fragment have two menus like setting,gridview.When i click the setting it perform the action but not in gridview.In each fragment first menu item only perform action not in second fragment.Please give me solution thanks.....

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settingmenu, menu);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menugridcalendar, menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_setting:
        Log.i(TAG,"InsdieGridmenu");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.gridmenuid:

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceof ListItemClickListener) {
            ((ListItemClickListener)activity).OpenGridView();
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;


}
```

Comment: Don't think that your menu.xml might be useful??? Seriously???

Comment: refer the following link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/